# Unable to Stream Picture from Azure Blob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a rest endpoint which I can't seem to stream out a picture from a valid Azure Blob. When I look at the stream in debug it has the appropriate byte sizes and appears to be healthy.

The following code works (*loading of Azure creds/container not shown for brevity*), but fails on output return (See 500 below)

```
if (await blockBlob.ExistsAsync())
{
     var stream = new MemoryStream();

     await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg");
```

---

**Result** 500 (Error: Internal Server Error):

```
server: Kestrel    
x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8BQzpcX0NvZGVcUGV0U21hcnRcUG9kc1xQT0RTXGN1c3RvbWVyc1xwaG90b3NcZG93bmxvYWQ=?= 
x-powered-by: ASP.NET   
date: Fri, 01 Jun 2018 21:21:18 GMT   
content-length: 0
```

---

**Endpoint**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/photos/download")]
[SwaggerOperation("Photo Download")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadPhoto([FromQuery]long? photoId)
```

---

This hard coded return works like a charm

```
var image = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Temp\info.png");
return File(image, "image/jpeg");
```

I can view and download the named blob in Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: You are unable to get the actual exception details from the 500?

Comment: No, both Postman and the swagger page, just report the headers as shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you forgot to seek the stream position back to 0.

Just add `stream.Position = 0;` after downloading the stream.